# How to backup the environment variable configuration for windows 10?

Tags: windows, backup, environment-variables

The situation is as follows:

Windows 10 22H2 (referred to as System A for short) cannot start (installed on hard drive A), nor can it enter safe mode or other startup modes, as starting will result in a blue screen (hard drive issue).

And there is another system (Windows 10 22H2) (referred to as System B) in another hard drive, and I want to export only the configuration information of System A during the export process.

How can I export the configuration information of environment variables in this system to other systems and apply it?

Comment: Environment variables won't help if the computer isn't booting. We need more info, like where during the boot process this happens and is there an error message?

Comment: @harrymc Unfortunately, my system is most likely hopeless. The blue screen codes are `0xc0000218` and `BAD SYSTEM PROFIG INFO` respectively, and that hard drive cannot be written to any data.

Comment: How do you know that it's impossible to write to the disk if the computer isn't booting?

Answer (score 0):

If you need the environment variables specifically, you can export them from the Registry.

1. Connect the old system disk, or somehow get the registry hive files from it.
2. On a working system, open `regedit`, select the HKLM root, then use "File → Load Hive" to access the necessary registry hive. Give it some arbitrary name.
3. Navigate to the subkey that stores environment variables; right-click to export them to a file.
4. Unload the old hive.
5. Edit the .reg file using Notepad or another text editor so that it will import at the correct location (i.e. change the `[key]` sections to say `[HKLM\SYSTEM\...]` instead of `[HKLM\MyTempHive\...]`), as well as removing unnecessary or duplicate variables that the target system already has anyway.
6. Import the .reg file to the target system.

For system-wide environment variables:

- File to load: `\Windows\System32\config\SYSTEM`
- Original base key: `HKLM\SYSTEM\`
- Subkey to export: `ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Environment`.

For per-user environment variables:

- File to load: `\Users\*\NTUSER.DAT`
- Original base key: `HKCU\`
- Subkey to export: `Environment`

Comment: Grafting another system's complete registry is dangerous with a good chance of creating new problems.

Comment: Good thing I'm not suggesting that, then.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with environmental variables.

From Microsoft's
[Error 0x74: Bad_system_config_info](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/error-0x74-bad-system-config-info-c0918f16-c812-2916-00d9-4387a3839f7c):

> This error means that something is wrong with the registry on your PC
> and you'll need to return to a previous configuration.
>
> 1. Turn off your PC by pressing and holding the power button, then turn it back on. When you see your PC manufacturer's logo, turn the PC
>    off again. Repeat the process until you see **Please wait**.
> 2. On the next screen, select **Troubleshoot**, then choose **Advanced options > System Restore**.
> 3. Choose an administrator account and enter the password. Select **Continue**.
> 4. Next, choose a restore point to restart your PC to. Select **last known good configuration**.
>
> If you're still having trouble or if there's no restore point
> available, [reset your PC](https://support.microsoft.com/help/12415).

After restoring the computer to working order, you need to
check the health of the disk.
Ask us if you need help in that direction.

Comment: I did not provide a detailed description of my system error in the question because this hard drive cannot be used to write any data, and sometimes even errors occur when reading data. For example, deleting or creating a new file on this hard drive, or deleting or adjusting a partition on this hard drive, will return to its original state after refreshing.

Comment: If you are interested, you can take a look at my [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1827847/i-am-unable-to-write-data-to-the-hard-drive-and-cannot-backup-it).