# I am unable to write data to the hard drive and cannot backup it

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, boot, backup

#### Known:

1. A hard drive is a solid-state drive with a 512GB SATA interface.
2. There are multiple partitions in hard drive A, each in sector order, used for [recovery/ESP (EFI partition)/MSR/Windows/Btrfs/BIOS Boot/Kali Linux/NTFS/NTFS/Ubuntu/Ubuntu Swap].
3. I am using a laptop and do not support UEFI startup.

#### Question:

One day before, I suddenly crashed while using the operating system (Parrot Sec OS, which uses Btrfs file system, hereinafter referred to as Parrot) on hard drive A.

I tried shortcut keys such as "Alt+PrtSc", "Ctrl+Alt+Delete", and "Ctrl+Alt+[F1/F2/F3/F4/F5/F6/F7]", but none of them were able to restore the system to normal or restart it. So after waiting for a while, I found that the system was still unresponsive, so I pressed and held down the power button to forcefully shut down.

When booting up again, it was found that all operating systems in hard drive A were unable to start.

The detailed error is that Kali Linux and Ubuntu will always get stuck in the startup animation interface when booting up. If you press ESC to view the output information, you will see a lot of errors.
Parrot will enter Busybox mode and cannot be fixed. If the Exit command is executed, it will get stuck in an error message and cannot be restarted or shut down (it can only be forcibly shut down using the power button).
The Windows 10 system will detect the hard drive and attempt to repair the blue screen every time it starts, randomly reporting one of the two blue screen codes [BAD SYSTEM CONFIG INFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x74--bad-system-config-info) and [0xc0000218](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0xc0000218--status-cannot-load-registry-file), which cannot be repaired.

#### Attempted solutions:

###### Fix for Windows:

It is useless to use Windows PE or Windows image to repair (including but not limited to `chkdsk`, `sfc`, `bootrec`, `bcdboot`), and also try to use the boot repair tool to call the `ntfsfix` command on the Linux boot disk (USB flash disk) to repair (`chkdsk` will be prompted).

###### Fix for Linux system:

Using `btrfs check (-- repair)`, `btrfs scrub (start)`, and `fsck` for repair is useless.

---

And during the repair process, I discovered an issue, which is that all partitions in hard drive A, after you have performed any operations on them (including but not limited to deleting partitions, formatting partitions, adjusting partition sizes, and deleting certain files in the partitions), Refreshing it will reveal that all operations have failed (for example, if you delete partition 1 in hard drive A, partition 1 will come back after refreshing, and the data inside will also be restored to the state before deleting the partition).

I really don't know what to do now, and I can't find the specific root cause of the problem. And it is currently very difficult for me to back up the data on hard drive A, because if I compress the data on this hard drive to another hard drive, it may become offline and unable to operate or copy.

Comment: The cause is the drive, the fix is replace it.

Comment: SSD's that are dying can fail "gracefully"  by becoming read-only, allowing one to recover data. Many fail completely, without chance of recovery, so consider yourself lucky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause of this is a failing SSD.

The better SSDs will protect your data by entering a read-only mode as they approach their true failure state. This allows you the greatest possible opportunity to access and save your data to another storage device before the drive fails completely.

You should get a replacement drive and begin copying the data as soon as possible.